# What is the best way to stop a process from running until previous query finishes?

Tags: kdb

I'm querying a large historical database (HDB) to select records by alphabet character, then upserting the selected records to another kdb table...

```
pullRecords:{[x]select from `ts where sym like x}
pushRecords:{[x]`newTS upsert x}
```

The actual database contains millions of rows of records. If I were to run this simultaneously for each character it would result in an `abort error` since it requires more memory than what's available.

The `ts` and `newTS` tables, which I set up for testing are below. I also set up a metadata table called `metaTable`, which has a `flag column` to signal when the query has finished running...

```
ts:([]sym:1000000?`A`Ab`B`Bc`C`Ca`X`Xz`Y`Yx`Z`Zy;price:1000000?100.0;num:til 10000
newTS:([]sym:`$(); price:`float$(); amt:`int$())
metaTable:([id:`char$()]flag:`boolean$())
```

I'd like to stop the script from running, based on the value of the `flag column`. If a  value of `1b` is found, it means the script is locked on that character, and no other characters can run their queries until the lock is reset to a negative boolean. If all values are equal to `0b` then the character checking the `flag column` acquires the lock (updates the value to `1b`),and runs their functions. Once the queries have completed the lock will be reset.

What I'd like to do is the following...

(1) Declare 2 variables.

```
setflag:1b
resetflag:0b
```

(2) Check flag column in `metaTable` and set to 1b if 0b.

```
if[select flag from metaTable where id like "A*"=resetflag;update flag:setflag from metaTable where id="A";'"Flag set"]
if[select flag from metaTable;'"Flag already set for char "A""]
```

(2a) The above fails with a `type error`. I can store the select query in a variable and then index into the variable but this doesn't return the updated value once it's been set.

```
chkflg:select flag from metaTable
if[chkflg.flag[0];...]
```

(3) Run `pullRecords` query, count rows of data pulled for character, run `pushRecords` query.

```
if[select flag from metaTable;pulled::pullRecords["A*"];'"Pulling data"]
amt:count pulled
if[select flag from metaTable;pushRecords[pulled];'"Pushing data"]
```

(4) Check amount of data pulled from `ts` equals amount of data pushed to `newTS`. If so, update the flag in `metaTable` from `1b` to `0b`. Unlock the script and start process for next character.

```
if[amt~count select from newTS where sym like "A*";update flag:resetflag from `metaTable where id="A";'"Lock released"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something similar to the **transaction** behavior. You could do this without using metaTable. You can use global variables(or variables in namespaces) to serve as a **lock**.

Below is an example template to setup on the master service(service which is handling concurrent requests). Modify it according to your setup.

Define 2 global variables- lock(boolean) to serve as lock and lock_char to store the current locked character.

```
 q) lock:0b
 q) lock_char:""
```

Define a function which will first check if the lock can be acquired(lock value=0b). If yes then get the lock and perform rest of the operations else show the message and return.

```
q) transaction:{[ch] if[lock;show "Currently locked for character:",lock_ch;:0b];
                / else acquire lock and perform other operations
                `lock set 1b; `lock_char set ch; s:ch,"*";
                `newTs upsert t: select from ts where sym like s;
                if[not count[t]=count select from newTs where sym like s;call_roolback_function[]];
                / reset lock
                `lock set 0b; `lock_char set "";
                :1b;
              }
```

Call function:

```
q) transaction "A"
```

Comment: Couldn't this be more re-usable and be generalized into a supervisor pattern, you simply sink the transaction into a function that the supervisor observes.  The observable can be either the sentinel return value that resets the lock, or a timeout.

Comment: Master service that I have mentioned is something similar to a supervisor with limited features. Supervisor pattern may or may not be useful because it depends upon what all services-tables application wants to lock. Also, every query in the system has to go through supervisor service else it could break the system easily.

Comment: In the second if statement, after comparing the count of t and newTs, what is the function of "call_rollback_function[]"?

Comment: Thats just the placeholder to put your cleanup function/operations before releasing the lock. Basically replace it with your cleanup/rollback function as if condition here says that something went wrong with table update.